# Display google chart date in dd MMM yyyy format

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-visualization

I am using google visualization for drawing chart. I need to show line hAxis date in( dd MMM yyyy) format I have tired format but it did not  helped

[image]

i need to display highlighted dates in correct format

Thanks

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/format-a-microsoft-json-date

Comment: Why is this tagged `c#` and `asp.net`?

Comment: i am using C# for server side code... sometime it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have find solution for my problem, i am posting solution so that it might help others

```
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('date', 'Column Name');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Temp. In Celsius');
        data.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'annotation' });
        data.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'annotationText' });

for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {              


data.addRow([ToJavaScriptDate(dataValues[i].ColumnName),dataValues[i].Value, 'Min Temp', 'Min temp']);
            }                 


  // used to convert  string to date 
    function ToJavaScriptDate(value) {
        var pattern = /Date\(([^)]+)\)/;
        var results = pattern.exec(value);
        return new Date(parseFloat(results[1]));
    }
```